# Scrolling QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, user-interface, scroll, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have QGraphicsScene instance set to QGraphicsView on the GUI with scrollbars enabled and full view port update. But when I scroll my graphics view I get the items added to qgraphics scene disappeared on some point, though they are added in code correctly and are expected to be displayed upon scroll ( custom class inherited from QGraphicsItem ):

```
  class CSquare : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
```

paint method is implemented as follows:

```
void CSquare::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    static int sz;
    painter->setFont(fnt_);
    painter->fillRect(this->r,this->br);
    painter->drawRect(this->r);
    //painter->drawText(this->p,this->txt);
    if (txt == "")
        return;
    if (fnt_.pixelSize()>0)
        sz = fnt_.pixelSize();
    else
        if (fnt_.pointSize()>0)
            sz = fnt_.pointSize();
        else
            if (fnt_.pointSizeF()>0)
                sz = fnt_.pointSizeF();

    switch (this->al_flag)
    {
    case 1:
        painter->drawText(this->p.x(),this->p.y(),sz*txt.size(),2*sz,Qt::AlignRight,this->txt);
        break;
    case 2:
        //painter->drawText(this->r,Qt::AlignLeft,this->txt);
        painter->drawText(this->p.x(),this->p.y(),sz*txt.size(),2*sz,Qt::AlignLeft,this->txt);
        break;
    case 3:
        //painter->drawText(this->r,Qt::AlignCenter,this->txt);
        painter->drawText(this->p.x(),this->p.y(),sz*txt.size(),2*sz,Qt::AlignCenter,this->txt);
        break;
    case 4:
        //painter->drawText(this->r,Qt::AlignJustify,this->txt);
        painter->drawText(this->p.x(),this->p.y(),sz*txt.size(),2*sz,Qt::AlignJustify,this->txt);
        break;
    }
}
```

One can see how they disappear on application run on this video screen cast:

[https://www.box.com/s/h4h94×1avgay1crzvyzx](https://www.box.com/s/h4h94%C3%971avgay1crzvyzx)

Can somebody hint what is the problem, how to resolve so the graphics items will not disappear on the view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That box.com link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Yep, sorry. The problem is already solved:
the problem was in custom function in the inherited class:

QRectF boundingRect() const;

That should return valid rectangle. Now I fixed that in my project and m going to remove the video.

Thank you for your attention.